# How to fix bricked Samsung Galaxy S4 GT i9505

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4, unbricking

My journey started when i decided to start playing around with things that i don't have experience with. I tried to enable usb debugging by flashing some file with **Odin** that was supposed to enable it but the phone started rebooting. Then i red how to fix it and i downloaded stock rom and i flashed it but this stuck me to the startup logo. I tried a software that was supposed to fix bricked phones FonePaw (Might be a scam programme but clearly did something because the phone tried to start with recovery mode). Then i tried to flash another rom because i thought that the first one might be bugged but the problem is still there. I also tried to flash **TWRP** but it didn't worked (Odin finished successfully but i couldnt use it). Now i'm at stage where the phone is stuck to startup logo. I can't go to recovery mode but download mode is still working. I have no experience with this so i'm wondering if it's even possible to fix the phone.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any important data you care about?

Comment: No this is my old phone.

Comment: Then it's easy. Just follow the official guides

Comment: Can you point me to them because i followed many guides and i'm not sure what will work. Thanks!

Comment: Wiki: https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxys4internationalqualcomm.html
XDA: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3742880
Download: https://dl.twrp.me/jfltexx

Comment: Wiki: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/jfltexx
XDA: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-develop#romList
Download: https://files.moskvich.xyz/LineageOS/14.1/jfltexx